# How to deal with Network Effects in AB Testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, networks

Say you wanted to AB test a particular treatment on a social network and measure the number of shares. Unfortunately, this is a very naive metric to use because we aren't accounting for the network affects in the AB test. That is, the stable unit treatment value is a bad approximation.

How would one deal with the network effects in the two groups, statistically speaking?

Comment: This paper (from LinkedIn employees) might provide a starting framework for helping think about this question: http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~hanj/pdf/www15_hgui.pdf